# Jsoup multiple class return empty

Tags: jsoup

I use Jsoup to scrape all

elements from the following DOM, but it return empty. I don't know where the error is.

```
<div class="content bold">
   <div class="main">
       <p>123</p>
       <p>456</p>
       <p>789</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the snippet of my code

```
Elements cont= doc.select(".main:has(p)");
System.out.println(cont.text());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Elements cont = doc.select(".main p");
```